# Getting data from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-analysis

I intend to analyze data derived from the user behavior on Stack Overflow (i.e. the number of questions asked in the last five years, upvotes, number of users common to "Android" and "iOS" dev environments, etc.). I have to use the data retrieved to create models depicting the manner in which these two technologies have grown over time. It would really help me if someone (who has prior experience with deriving data from Stack Exchange) could give some inputs on this.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Are you stuck with some part of the process? Try to add more detail so people can give you specific advice.

Comment: When it comes back online, you can get all your data from  http://data.stackexchange.com, I'm sure.

Comment: The box is back up and we're copying databases across the network now, ETA to it being usable again is about 30 min

Comment: For starters, there doesn't seem to be any resource that I could use to get started with [link](data.stackexchange.com). I'm not at all aware of the underlying schema of this database and I suppose that I would have to query it to get the needed details. If you know of any online resource that I could use, I'd be obliged.

Comment: @r2j2 - the schema is listed on the right-hand side as part of the data explorer.  Additionally, we are preparing a data dump based on that very data now...the hardware upgrade we just performed was partially for a fully automated data dump we try and provide on a regular basis...automating it should make it regular again.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some queries to get you started:

- [The number of questions asked in the last five years](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382665#graph)
- [upvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382666#graph)
- [number of users common to "Android" and "iOS" dev environments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382667) (415,220 at the time of posting)

More ready-made queries can be found in [What SEDE examples would be most useful to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239639/what-sede-examples-would-be-most-useful-to-new-users)

The explanation of the schema can be found in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) and The Data Explorer as a [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) for itself. The database is hosted in a SQL Server instance so you can use [most of the T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499(v=sql.110).aspx) statements.

In [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250439/158100) you'll find an ERD model.