# Database Diagram of Stack Exchange model?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump

I went over the [Archive site](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) where I could retrieve data from Astronomy.SE. After I downloaded the content, I found 8 XML files that came maybe from a dump process.

Now I am not able to assemble all the data inside a database to perform query over it. Even if I go to [its SEDE site](https://data.stackexchange.com/astronomy/queries), it is hard to create a good query because I don't know the entity-relationship model.

Is there a place where we could see the ERD of Stack Exchange model? Is the complete diagram composed only by 8 tables? Does someone have used any tool to assembly those 8 tables?

The best post I found was this one but not solved the problem completely:
[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Comment: It would help to say in what way the post on database schema is incomplete.

Comment: it is not incomplete. It is not fitting the 8 dumped files. So how can we use this 18 tables post to create a schema of 8 tables dumped?

Comment: Did the [readme](https://ia801500.us.archive.org/8/items/stackexchange/readme.txt) help any?

Comment: Some people used to maintain scripts to convert the data dumps into common database formats ([example](https://github.com/SamSaffron/So-Slow)), but I don't know if any of those are still around.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no visual representation of the database schema of the Data Explorer maintained, so I think this will be the first one.

This is what I have after a couple of hours for writing a script and fiddling a little bit with draw.io. Remember this is not fully generated, I had to touch up the image to unclutter it a little bit (and I left out all the `*Types` tables).

> [image: ERD of SEDE]

<sup>*Click the image for larger variant.*</sup>

The cardinalities are OK-ish, but I didn't bother to hunt down all zero/one base ends. And I did use SEDE as my starting-point which is a little bit richer in tables.

You can generate a working-copy that you can import in [draw.io](https://www.draw.io) by running the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281389/generate-draw-io-erd-of-sede). If you download the query result as [CSV](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/csv/366152) and open that file in your favorite editor, you will see something like this:

```
"<mxGraphModel dx=""835"" dy=""760"" grid=""1"" gridSize=""10"" guides=""1"" tooltips=""1"" connect=""1"" fold=""1"" page=""1"" pageScale=""1"" pageWidth=""826"" pageHeight=""1169"" style=""default-style2"" math=""0"">
    <root>
        <mxCell id=""0""/>
 .... many more lines skipped
    </root>
</mxGraphModel>"
```

Remove the first and the last double-quote (") and then do replace all on double-double-quotes to double-quotes. To get a result similar to this:

```
<mxGraphModel dx="835" dy="760" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="826" pageHeight="1169" style="default-style2" math="0">
    <root>
        <mxCell id="0"/>
        <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
        <mxCell 
            style="swimlane;html=1;childLayout=stackLayout;horizontal=1;startSize=32;horizontalStack=0;fillColor=#008cff;fontColor=#FFFFFF;rounded=1;fontSize=17;fontStyle=0;strokeWidth=2;resizeParent=0;resizeLast=1;shadow=0;dashed=0;align=center;;swimlaneLine=0"
            id="245575913"
            parent="1" 
            vertex="1" 
            value="Users">
                <mxGeometry 
                    as="geometry" 
                    height="392" 
                    width="150" 
                    y="100" 
                    x="2100"/>
        </mxCell>
```

If you save this file as XML, you can use the import function in draw.io to get the visual representation of that XML. After that, you can choose to *Auto-layout (Organic)* and then un-clutter some of the lines and entities by moving them around.

By no means this ERD or script is fully complete. Consider it as a starting point. I'm happy to take feature requests and see what I can do in the next couple of weeks.

Answer (score 13):

The Schema Visualized
[image: SEDE ERD]
The Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) above was constructed using the data found in the *information_schema.columns* table. (Thank you to [ashleedawg](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1023678/1114977/all-tables-columns-data-typesincl-length-or-precision-in-sede) for paring that table further down to its bare essentials). Python 3 was used to convert all the table, column and key information into a SQL script. The ERD was reverse engineered using *dbschema*.

Please find the script and other related files in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/leerssej/SEDESchema).

The interactive HTML version of the ERD is posted up here:
https://sedeschema.github.io/