# There are no foreign-keys constraints in the data-explorer database

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

While creating the answer for [Database Diagram of Stack Exchange model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250396/database-diagram-of-stack-exchange-model/250439#250439) I was looking for the schema information stored in the SEDE database. The [sys.tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) and [sys.columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) are populated but when I was looking for the foreign-key constraints I found the [sys.foreign_keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) table to be empty.

I assume that is because it doesn't add much value to a read-only database schema to have referential constraints defined and it would require extra care when importing data but would it actually harm useability if we have them?

I now use this [query to list foreign-key relations](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281859/foreign-keys) but if that information is added to the db we can generate part of the [db schema post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) and annotate it with the relations, it could help new users to understand the schema better and I could use it in the ERD generation script (or someone could create an even more awesome way).

Can we consider to add the foreign-key-constraints to the SEDE databases?