# Is there a site dedicated to Stack Exchange Data Explorer questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-exchange, data-explorer, data-dump

Where should I ask questions about the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

I found [this page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) which explains that stack exchange data is dumped somewhere, and in the [help section](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) I am told to ask questions about the data explorer here (on Meta Stack Exchange):

Surprisingly there exists a "Frequently Asked Questions" section in the help page of the stack exchange data explorer page instead of the link I expected to a Stack Exchange site on which to ask questions. In fact the FAQ section of the help page seems to indicate that those questions are currently rolled into Meta Stack Exchange.

> To get help with your Data Explorer question though, or to provide feedback, please ask on Meta Stack Exchange!

Is there reason for not having a dedicated StackExchange site for questions related to queries on stack exchange data? In particular, wouldn't it be nice to have a place dedicated to asking questions about using the "Data Explorer", "Stack Exchange Data Dump Formats", and any existing queries?

Comment: What type of problems are you having? Getting particular queries to work (that sounds like a variation on an SQL problem which might be appropriate for Stack Overflow)? or descriptions of the structures (that's more a meta question which would show up here)? Something else?

Comment: There is a lot fo content here already like [the data dictionary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), [interesting queries](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) and I have [answered a question that asked about an ERD of SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250439/158100)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is there a good reason to have one that is dedicated to the data explorer?

An extra site is overkill (there are currently 842 questions tagged with [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)). A site is not free - there is a database behind it, web resources, and extra maintenance work, which is simply not worth it in this case.

Having a whole site dedicated to this makes no sense (there isn't a community around the tool - with only 842 question in 6 years, this would be a site that would probably not survive a private beta).

Comment: Yes.  Those questions will get seen and answered here; there wouldn't be enough people who would regularly visit a separate site.