# Get bounty reason in data explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to understand which bounty reasons get the most usage, but I can't find the bounty reason anywhere in the database schema.

Also, is there any way to do a keyword search on all the table names and fields in the schema?

Comment: Well, it's not available anywhere, so good chance it's lost for good. (It's not available in the revisions.)

Answer (score 4):

The bounty reason is now stored in the public dataschema. Let me first show you can get the id for the [post notice](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/531047) from the PostHistory

```sql
select top 1000 v.postid as [Post Link]
     , v.creationdate as [vote date]
     , ph.creationdate as [post notice datetime]
     , ph.text
     , ph.comment
     , v.bountyamount
     --  v.userid as [User Link]
from votes v 
inner join posthistory ph on ph.postid = v.postid
where  v.votetypeid = 8 -- bounty start
and ph.posthistorytypeid = 33 -- post notice added
and v.creationdate = cast(ph.creationdate as date)
order by v.creationdate desc
```

The number in the comment matches with the primary key of the PostNotices table.
Here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/632222) that gives you the number of times a certain bounty reason is chosen:

```sql
select name
     , count(*) [# used]
from postnotices pn
inner join postnoticetypes pt on pt.id = pn.postnoticetypeid
where classid = 2 -- Bounty
group by name
order by count(*) desc
```

When run today you'll get the following result:

[image: result of counts per bounty reason]

In the PostNotices table you'll also find the custom text entered by users when they set the bounty.

I leave joining PostHistory and PostNotice as an exercise for the reader.

For your second question either use ctrl+F in the browser or you can query the [views in the information_schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms186778.aspx), for example [`columns`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/531037?keyword=user):

```sql
select table_name
     , column_name
     , data_type
from information_schema.columns
where table_name like '%' + ##keyword:string## + '%'
or column_name like '%' + ##keyword:string## + '%'
```

when you run that for keyword *user* you get this result:

[image: result of colmuns query]

But maybe you didn't find [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) or the [Database Diagram of Stack Exchange model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250396/database-diagram-of-stack-exchange-model/250439#250439) which might give an better idea of what is possible/available.

Comment: I thought the tables and fields listed in the right column of the query editor were all the available fields. It seems adding a textbox to search in there wouldn't be super complicated.

Comment: @bigblind that is true, I forgot most browser have a Ctrl+F function nowadays. Added that to my answer. Maybe a userscript is possible as well to add a searchbox