# Data Explorer query to get my post with specific tag

Tags: support, data-explorer

I would like to select all my posts with a specific tag with Data Explorer. Some posts may have multiple tags. If my specific tag is say `powerbi` I would like to select also all the posts that have `powerbi` and `dax` tags.

BTW is there any graph how the tables of Data Explorer are related?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/887771?tag=powerbi&UserId=1903793) does what you want

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , case when p.posttypeid = 1 then 'Q' else 'A' end [Q/A]
from posts p
inner join posts q 
        on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) -- only questions have tags
where q.tags like '%<##tag?powerbi##>%'
and p.owneruserid = ##userid?1903793##
and p.posttypeid in (1,2)
```

Alternatively, if you want to select multiple tags:

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , case when p.posttypeid = 1 then 'Question' else 'Answer' end [Q/A]
from posts p
inner join posts q 
        on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) -- only questions have tags
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = q.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
cross join string_split(##tags:string?powerbi,dax##, ',') tv
where t.tagname = tv.value
and p.owneruserid = ##userid?1903793##
and p.posttypeid in (1,2)
```

A partial ERD can be found in [Database Diagram of Stack Exchange model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250396/database-diagram-of-stack-exchange-model/250439#250439)

For the Data Dictionary see [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday morning. If you're new to SEDE you might like the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and if you have additional questions, feel free to hop in [SEDE Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede)