# Remove the underline on links to duplicate targets on duplicate closures

Tags: feature-request, design, duplicate-questions, hyperlinks

I noticed that today, the team changed the style of hyperlinks in posts to show an underline. This [has been clarified to be by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314284/).

However, I think that this is too cluttered in links to duplicate targets:

[image]

Can the underline please be removed on links to duplicate targets, on questions closed as duplicates? It's way too eye-catching and distracting for me.

I understand that it can't be removed on older duplicates where the Community user edited in the link, so this request applies to newer closures only.