# What's the reason to make link in the spam post bold?

Tags: support, bug, design, hyperlinks, spam

In the deleted as spam post the link to the revision history is bold styled:

> [image: bold link]

You can check [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322682/339911) for an instance.

Is there a background to make such a link bold or merely an oversight?

BTW, if I recall correctly such links were underlined ever before [changing the link style globally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314275/339911) on Stack Exchange.

Comment: So you __know it's important__.

Comment: @TheWanderer what is important?

Comment: The link is important.

Comment: @TheWanderer we hide abusive content from your eyes, but here is the **important link** to that? I think it should be written in **CAPS** and also blinks! With a loud sound escort of course.

Comment: maybe a marquee